# Автоматическое добавление строк при нехватке места для текста

Tags: javascript, html, css

Представил на картинке ниже. Если не будет хватать места то добавится ещё одна строка. Возможно ли сделать такое только на `CSS`. Если нет, то хотелось бы увидеть решение на чистом `JS`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попытался сделать с `CSS`. Возможно лучше использовать `textarea`, но мне нужно подчеркивание строк.

```css
input[type="text"] {
  width: 80px;
  word-break: break-all;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Обычный `div` изначально ведет себя именно так - добавляет себе высоты по мере необходиомсти.

```css
div {
  background: black;
  color:red;
  padding:2em;
  font-size:20px;
  text-decoration:underline;
  max-width:200px;
  margin-right:2em;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div>
Тут меньше текста <br>
Строка текста <br>
Строка текста <br>
<b>Строка текста </b>
Строка текста <br>
Строка текста <br>
</div>


<div>
Тут больше текста <br>
И под него выделяется место <br>
Строка текста <br>
<b>Строка текста </b><br>
Строка текста <br>
<h1>Строка текста </h1>
Строка текста <br>
Строка текста 
</div>
```

И, да, `textarea` прекрасно обстиливается, в том числе и подчеркивание строк работает. А вот добавление высоты автоматом для `textarea` как раз тот еще геморрой...

Обычно делают так: Создают нужный `div`, поверх накладывают (или в него вкладывают) невидимую `textarea` с теми же отступами-шрифтами-размерами и скрипт на каждое изменение в `textarea` меняет содержимое `div`'а.

---

Но самый труъ вариант - современный: добавить элементу атрибут `contenteditable="true"`. Во: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pMzEOK

Comment: и правда звучит сложновато, может быть есть более элегантное решение? :)

Comment: Есть, но только для современных браузеров. Добавил в ответ.

Comment: Оффтопик: чтобы ваше подчеркивание текста не превращалось в гэ, по умолчанию включенное в современном Хроме, добавьте стиль `text-decoration-skip-ink: none`. Или более универсально - заверните текст в `<div><span>...</span></div>`, спану добавьте нижний бордер и сделайте редактируемым именно его - тогда можно будет манипулировать габаритами и отступами подчеркивания, а по высоте будет распираться родитель-див.